# Can't add Table inside TableCell dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a table object which I am creating dynamically in back end.

```
 Table tblNewHeaderModule = new Table();
 TableRow trModuleTitleRow = new TableRow();
 TableCell tcModuleTitleCell = new TableCell();

 trModuleTitleRow.Cells.Add(tcModuleTitleCell);            
 tblNewHeaderModule.Rows.Add(trModuleTitleRow);
```

I am trying to add a new table inside the tcModuleTitleCell table cell.

```
 Table tblContent = new Table();
 TableRow trContentHeader = new TableRow();

 TableCell tcContentTitle = new TableCell();           
 tcContentTitle.Text = "some text";

 trContentHeader.Cells.Add(tcContentTitle);
 tblContent.Rows.Add(trContentHeader);

 tcModuleTitleCell.Controls.Add(tblContent);
```

When the code runs, I can not see the child table. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You created all the controls and forget to add the master table to the page or any other container in the page :

```
Page.Controls.Add(tblNewHeaderModule);
```

Comment: No No I have added the master table inside a panel already, and the master table is loading properly. only the child table does not show up.

Comment: It's rendered correctly in page also inside Asp.net Panel .
I got the following HTML :

<div id="MainContent_pnl1">
 
Text in panel
<table>
  <tr>
   <td><table>
    <tr>
     <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
   </table></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>